# How to display a list of relative layouts?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am having a problem, I am a web developer, I am used to CSS and I am so good at it, I thought it is gonna be the same for Android design but I am having a bad time really, I spent almost half of the day just designing only the top menu and place two buttons below it and I don't think I did even correctly, Now I have a bloc where I display an Image, Username and button on the right, Here is how it looks :

```
     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ajouter"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40px"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30px"

                    />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/bun"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="something"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10px"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="350px"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="45px"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0px"

                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        tools:text="AkkaBook"></TextView>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100px"
                        android:layout_height="100px"
                        android:layout_marginTop="40px"
                        android:layout_marginRight="40px"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40px"
                        android:id="@+id/profgilImg"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></ImageView>

                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

It is a Relative Layout that has to containais many relative layouts, each one of those child relative layouts has the content ( image - username - button ). I managed to do just one but when I copy and paste the code to have a full list, everything start looking ugly.

Here is what I did looks like :

[image]

What I want is a List :

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A Recycler View would be your best bet ,since then you can add the data dynamically once and it will automatically populate the view with the new data and this would be much easier.

Try this: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example

Comment: Does anyone have any resources to help a web developer transition into understanding android layouts?

Comment: @KennyJohnJacob I was dreaming of that, because it is so important to find such things easily, but I always had problems with that :(

Answer (score 2):

You have to use two different layouts.Because i think that you have one main layout which includes a recyclerView and an item layout for your recyclerView. Your layouts should be like this.

Main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHeader"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="LISTE DES AMIS"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="SUGGESTIONS"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayoutHeader"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

     <!-- put your recyclerView here -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

RecyclerView Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#e1e1e2">

    <View
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/viewView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Akka Book"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="AJOUTER"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Prefer ConstraintLayout rather than RelativeLayout for better performance.Thats all

Answer (score 1):

You should user RecyclerView or ListView which has the adapter with Relative Layout item.

[RecyclerView  ( I recommend you to follow this guide )](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

[ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView)

[Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)